# How to install multiple versions of Acrobat Reader on one machine

Tags: installation, adobe-acrobat

Is it possible? I tried to install 8 when I have 9 installed but the installer bombed out when it saw version 9.

Any ideas how to work around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three options:

1) Side load install. This is where you start with the lowest version, moving upwards. Making sure to install each to a separate location and not upgrading. You may not be able to do this due to the limitations of the installer.

2) VMware. Setup a virtual machine with one of the versions installed. This is a heavyweight solution just to get a pdf reader.

3) Sandboxie. go to http://www.sandboxie.com/ and install the software. Run each installer in a different sandbox and launch the .exe as needed. This is a light weight solution.

That being said I have a question: why do you want multiple versions of reader on your computer? What are you trying to do? All reader 8 files should be compatible with reader 9.

Comment: The reason is because I am attempting to prove what I currently believe to be a but in Reader 9. If older versions of the program act the same way...that will tell me my PDF generation program is broke, otherwise...I will have more evidence!

Comment: Then a VM is the way to go. Any time you need to do troubleshooting, it's best to isolate the "test bed" in it's own environment. If you had access to another machine, you could install different readers on each and run your test. That's the most straightforward approach.